# How can one specify the window title for a console application started with System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()?

Tags: .net, processstartinfo

I am starting a new instance of a console application from my .NET code using the `Process.Start()` method. I was wondering if I can specify the title of the console window hosting the spawned process. Could not find anything suitable in `ProcessStartInfo`.

As a last resort I can P/Invoke to talk to Win32 API directly, but I'd rather not.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it sounds like you know the P/Invoke way of doing this, but for anyone else this is how you do it

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetWindowText(IntPtr hwnd, string title);


SetWindowText(myProcess.MainWindowHandle, "my new title");
```

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847418/how-do-i-change-the-window-title-after-starting-something-with-process-start, it looks like a Thread.Sleep() is needed - on my machine, a sleep of 1000ms does the trick. Not sure how to make it more robust (i.e. not rely on an arbitrary delay).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I can think of is to create a batch file that sets the title (using the title command) and then executes the application. Then Start the .bat file instead.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. Does it mean that there is no way in .NET?

Answer (score 3):

Inside the e.g. script of powershell I do use:

```
# Set the Window Title as a reference
[System.Console]::Title = "Main title of the window"
```

Got it from here, maybe useful:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rob/archive/2012/08/21/setting-the-title-of-the-command-prompt-window.aspx