# How do I change/set the Window Title on execution? Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, window, title, execution

Basic question but I find no solution. This is my code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml


Public Class Etiquetes

Private Sub saveXML_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles saveXML.Click
    Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
    settings.Indent = True

    Me.Text = "The title I want"

    Dim XmlWrt As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("C:\Documents and Settings\dpradell\Etiqueta.xml", settings)

    With XmlWrt



        .WriteStartElement("Production")
        .WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsd", Nothing, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
        .WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", Nothing, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")

        .WriteStartElement("Order")

        .WriteStartElement("Attribute")
        .WriteAttributeString("Type", "NumReparacio")
        .WriteAttributeString("Value", txtNumReparacio.Text.ToString())
        .WriteEndElement()


    End With

    MessageBox.Show("XML guardat")
End Sub

End Class
```

So as you can see, I know how to change it when I click the button with this:

```
 Me.Text = "The title I want"
```

But how do I set it before the application executes? Or how do I change it just when it starts? Thank you very much!

Comment: Seems to be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847418/how-do-i-change-the-window-title-after-starting-something-with-process-start

Comment: Doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward (once I found it that is)

```
My.Forms.Form1.Text = "Whatever name you want here"
```

Add this into your form's load event handler.